# Try/Catch works well in debug but not in .exe

Tags: vb.net, debugging, try-catch, release, exe

There's a TL;DR version down the post above the questions.
I have a program that has a reference to an external assembly, which I can't manage. It basically manages the connection to a Card PinPad reader and organizes the information read from said cards. There is some simple code:

```
    Try
        pinpad.readcard(lecturaEntrada, lecturaSalida)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed Card read " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

What happens here is that Pinpad waits for a card to read, and the user can cancel it clicking on cancel on the device. Throwing an exception, with ex.message reading "Canceled by user". I'm pretty sure it's a created/managed exception, since its not really a system exception. So I can reproduce the error/exception everytime I want with 100% rate.

I did several tests with it and every time it threw the exception. After that, I exported it to production/test pc. Just to notice it doesnt work anymore. And after a lot of tinkering around I found out that running the program on VStudio debug runtime, try catch works perfectly. And whenever I used the executable, be it on target PC or on my own DEV PC, the executable try catch is faulty, and doesnt catch anything, only to crash the program.

TLDR: program has a try catch routine. It works fine within VS2010 debug runtime, and  doesnt work when you use the .exe

Is there anything I can do in order for it to work? Is there something happening that I dont know of behind the scenes during the creation of the executable that is eliminating the programs ability to try catch?

Edit: Ive tried turning optimizations off, running as administrator, to no avail. Google hasnt thrown any asnwers either

Edit: heres the stack trace as is:

```
en Banorte.NET.procearExcepcion(APIException* e)
en Banorte.PinPan.PinPadVerifone.leertarjeta(hashtable parametrosEntrada, hashtable parametrosSalida)
en PruebasPinPad.form.btnPagoTDC_click(objectsender,eventargs e) en C:\VS2010\PruebasPinPad\Form.vb:linea191
```

Also there are no inner exceptions

Edit: I found this stacktrace when I tried to directly debug the .exe:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.
  Source=BanortePinPad
  StackTrace:
       en std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.{dtor}(basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* )
       en APIException.{dtor}(APIException* )
       en ___CxxCallUnwindDtor(IntPtr pDtor, Void* pThis)
       en leerTarjetaEx(map<std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >\,std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >\,std::less<std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> > >\,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> > const \,std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> > > > >* mapaParametrosEntrada, map<std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >\,std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >\,std::less<std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> > >\,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> > const \,std::basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> > > > >* mapaParametrosSalida)
       en Banorte.PinPad.PinPadVerifone.leerTarjeta(Hashtable parametrosEntrada, Hashtable parametrosSalida)
       en PruebasPinPAD.Form.btnPagoTDC_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\VS2010\PruebasPinPAD\Form.vb:línea 191
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       en Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       en Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       en Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       en PruebasPinPAD.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) en 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:línea 81
```

Heres and edit to bump my question a bit up. Thanks in advance for any help and thanks to  anyone that has tried to help so far. Im still trying to figure this out.

Edit: I just saw an error debugging the exe and it reads. AccessViolationException was unhandled. and not being able to read/write in protected memory.

Comment: Is the try catch code in your main ?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exception/stack trace caught when in debug mode? This may provide some clues as to why your release build won't catch this. Remember to include any inner exceptions as well.

Comment: Is it really this try-catch that fails?
I see that you are reading cards which probably means you are tinkering with USB and ports and whatnot.
What if you are running VS with elevated privileges and the error is somewhere else - closer to the USB or the readcard code?
Are you running some sort of unknown 3rd party unsafe code and VS protects you?

Comment: Never, ever instantiate and throw a System.Exception object... Always use a subclass to instantiate from, even if you have to create it yourself, as this gives your code some context to work with... At the moment, any exception that occurs will bleed the Exception.Message property to the user! In short, tightly define the exceptions you will raise, and tightly restrict what you catch...

Comment: @Ha11owed Code is inside a button, after some creation of hastables and whatnot.

Comment: @LosManos Yes it is, other trys work fine. I am using a USB PinPad, and it works ok, it has nothing to do with conections or ports. I have tested it after that exception during debug and it maintains conection and I can still do other things after that. Run a administrator delivered same results

Comment: @MartinMilan That is a nice tip, and I did have it set more tightly as
    Catch ex as Banorte.banorteexception
Since thats the assembly exception, but I started to get mad that it didnt catch and crashed the app, o I set it with a wide spectrum to see if it catched anything and it didnt

Comment: @Kev Stacktrace in main post, and its not really thte release build, I can use the exe created inside the debug folder and wont work. the problem i the .exe not the debug/relase build perse

Comment: What version of .NET?

Comment: It's coded with VS2010, in VB.net with framework 4.0(full, no client), assembly as I recently found out was made with VS2005 in VC++, framework 2.0, It is running in mixed mode since framework 2.0 and 4.0 are there toghether.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are dealing with a non-CLS compliant exception.

To catch any non-CLS compliant exception you will need to have an empty catch:

```
try { }
catch { }
```

In VB:

```
Try
Catch
End Try
```

so your code should be something like:

```
Try
    pinpad.readcard(lecturaEntrada, lecturaSalida)
Catch
   MsgBox("Failed Card read")
   Exit Sub
End Try
```

Comment: I tried this as you so kindly indicated but it didnt work =´(, same thing as before, works whithin VStudio (as it did before) but not with the standalone.exe. Thank you for your effort, Im still working on it.